# javascript string comparison issue in array.filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, string-comparison

I have an array which contains following objects.

```
myArray = [
    { item: { id: 111557 } },
    { item2: { id: 500600 } }]
```

and I have a variable

```
targetItemID = '111557'
```

Note that one is string, and the ones in array are numbers. I'm trying to get the object having the correct item id.

Here is what I  have tried,

```js
    myArray = [
        { item: { id: 111557 } },
        { item2: { id: 500600 } }]


    
    targetItemID = '111557'
    
var newArray = myArray.filter(x => {

    console.log(x.item.id.toString())
    console.log(targetItemID.toString())

    x.item.id.toString() === itemID.toString()

    })

    console.log(newArray);
```

I expect all matching objects to be added to 'newArray'. I tried to check the values before comparison, They are both strings, they seem exactly same, but my newArray is still empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First, not all your objects have an `item` property, so you'll need to check it exists. Second, you're comparing them against a non-existent `itemID` instead of `targetItemID`, and finally, and @bryan60 mentioned, if you open a block in an anonymous lambda, you need an explicit `return` statement, although, to be honest, you really don't need the block in this case:

```
var newArray =
    myArray.filter(x => x.item && x.item.id && x.item.id.toString() === targetItemID)
```

Answer (score 3):

- Your second object doesn't have an `item` property and should.
- You need a `return` in your `filter` function.
- You must compare `x.item.id` against `targetItemID`, not `itemID`. Since you are using `console.log()` you would have seen and error of `itemID id not defined` ;).

```js
myArray = [
        { item: { id: 111557 } },
        { item: { id: 500600 } }
];


targetItemID = '111557'
    
var newArray = myArray.filter(x => {

    //console.log(x.item.id.toString())
    //console.log(targetItemID.toString())

    return x.item.id.toString() === targetItemID.toString();
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: yep he needs to return the condition

Comment: oh yes, that's a typo. return keyword was the problem for me, it's solved, thanks

Comment: @neiloth Please up vote all answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to return for filter to work:

```
return x.item.id.toString() === itemID.toString();
```

Comment: Oh thanks, good catch :) I'll mark as correct answer in 9 mins.

Comment: There's more to it than just this. See my answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i dont know how I didn't see your answer first :) thanks, I will mark yours.

Comment: @ScottMarcus true didn't read that carefully / assumed they were typos